# How to add include_directory in simple CMake Project

Tags: cmake

I have CMake project whose directory structure is as follows:

```
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── headers
│   │   └── utility.h
│   └── main.cpp
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── testfeature_a
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── test_me.cpp
    └── test_main.cpp
```

In test_me.cpp I wanted to include utility.h as I wanted to test functions defined there. So I did **#include "headers/utility.h"** and in testfeature_a CMakeLists.txt I did this:

```
file(GLOB SRCS *.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(testfeature_a ${SRCS})
include_directories(src/headers)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    testfeature_a
    libgtest
    libgmock
)
add_test(NAME testfeature_a

     COMMAND testfeature_a)
```

But the make fails with the error message ***fatal error: headers/utility.h: No such file or directory.***
How can I include the headers directory in test_me.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path in `include_directories()` may be incorrect. Here are two things that you could check

1. The file seems to be the CMakeLists.txt in tests-folder so you need to go up one folder before you can go to src-folder, i.e. `include_directories(../src/headers)`.
2. You repeat the headers-folder in the `#include "headers/utility.h"` when you have already specified it in `include_directories(src/headers)`. Either use `#include "utility.h"` in cpp-file or `include_directories(src)` in CMakeLists.txt.

Other option is that you don't need to specify the headers-folder in the CMakeLists.txt at all. You can simply use `#include "path/to/your/file.h` without any other configuration.

For debugging your path in the CMakeLists.txt you can call [message](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/message.html)-function, e.g. `message(${your_path})`, so it's printed when executed and you can check if it's correct.

In addition you can use CMake built-in variables such as [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) and [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html), e.g. `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/headers)`